# .NET Core Docker Image for Linux-arm (Raspberry pi)

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, .net-6.0

I made a simple **.Net 6.0 console app** and i built it using dotnet publish command with the flag of linux-arm

> dotnet pubish -c release -r linux-arm

Above generates the linux ARM dll's.

Then I created an image for it using *Dockerfile*

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
 COPY bin/Release/net6.0/linux-arm /MyDockerApp
 WORKDIR /MyDockerApp
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

(I am not building it, since my code is already built for arm-v7 using dotnet publish)

Now I am trying to run this image as a container on my Raspberry pi (which is Arm/Linux/v7) and i am getting below error.

> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match
> the detected host platform (linux/arm/v7) and no specific platform was
> requested standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec
> format error

How can I compile it so I can run it on my Raspberrypi 4 (I dont want to build my code on Raspberry pi, I just want to use the RunTime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use corresponding ARM [.NET runtime image](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-aspnet) for your `RaspberryPI` in your `Dockerfile`

For example, this one should work

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0.0-focal-arm32v7
```

instead of default

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0
```

which is for regular PC.

Comment: by doing that I get error: The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '6.0.0' (arm) was not found.

Comment: You said that you have a _console_ app, so I supposed it's not an ASP.NET app. Anyway, in this case you can change mentioned line to `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0.0-focal-arm32v7`. Because ASP.NET has a separate runtime image

Comment: doing that gives me error: Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Looks like it's already an application error. Are there more details in the error?

Comment: I spent days on this, I took the same solution, downgraded it to dot 3.1 framework and same code works fine on PI. it seems like Raspbeery pi support for .NET 6 has some issues.

Comment: Feel free to ask more detailed question with your code

Comment: it turns out my pi was running Debian 10 (Buster ), Upgraded to Bullseye and same code runs just fine.